# how to plot graph for one pandas dataframe cell with respect to some columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am new to data plotting, matplotlib or sns library. 
There is a

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.random.rand(10,4)
y[:,0]= np.arange(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=["X", "A", "B", "C"])

df.head()
```

[image]

```
df.plot(x='X', y=['A', 'B', 'C'], kind='bar')
```

[image]

How can I plot `df.plot(y='1.0', x=['A', 'B', 'C'], kind='bar')`  # *I want to put cell as X or Y axis.*

I have copied the example from StackOverflow itself.

Comment: Row plot can be said. I tried `df.iloc[1].plot(y=['A','B','C'])` . Instead of index I want to pick specific column cell.

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: This is a small dataset I have a bigger one so I want to see the change of values as a continuous line graph with respect to columns like 'A', 'B','C' ....

Answer (score 2):

in the code below, you can select row values and graph them by their types, you can do this for each row, and you can analyse each col/row you want with it.

```
#df.plot(x='X',y=['A','B','C'],kind = 'bar')
y1 = df.iloc[0,1:].values #for first column (horizontal values)
x1 = ['A','B','C']
plt.plot(x1,y1)
```

this one was for 0.th row,

Comment: you can also add title, xlabel, ylabel to analyse better